# Routing between physical networks through netns without NAT

Tags: linux-networking

I'm trying to route between a network attached to a device inside a netns and network outside the netns just using iptables FORWARD and ip route the same(ish) as between interfaces within the same netns, but not making too much progress. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something fundamental, but I've hit a block and no amount of searching the internet so far is yielding anything useful.

I have bond0 connected to my switch with bond0.1 being in the default netns on 196.168.100.1/24, and bond0.555 being inside netns sip on 192.168.136.1/24. Communication from processes inside the netns to their respective devices work fine. (in this case I'm running asterisk inside the netns as it needs different default routes, etc. for this specific solution, that part won't change.)

192.168.100.1 is the default route for all devices on vlan1

192.168.136.1 is the default route for all devices on vlan555

Now I'm wanting to be able to communicate from vlan1 to vlan555 from outside the server and netns. What I've tried is:

```
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth0 netns sip
ip link set veth0 up
ip netns exec sip ip link set veth0 up
ip addr add 172.25.36.1/24 dev veth0
ip netns exec sip ip addr add 172.25.36.2/24 dev veth0
ip route add 192.168.136.0/24 via 172.25.36.1
ip netns exec sip ip route add 192.168.100.0/24 via 172.25.36.2
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.136.0/24 -d 192.168.100.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.136.0/24 -s 192.168.100.0/24 -j ACCEPT
ip netns exec sip iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.100.0/24 -d 192.168.136.0/24 -j ACCEPT
ip netns exec sip iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.100.0/24 -s 192.168.136.0/24 -j ACCEPT
ip netns exec sip sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

After which, from the default netns I can ping 192.168.136.1, and from the sip netns I can ping 192.168.100.1, but I can't reach any devices across the netns to the respective network, nor can I reach 192.168.136.1 from a device on vlan1, or 192.168.100.1 from a device on vlan555.

I did try making a bridge inside the netns between bond0.555 and veth0, but that didn't seem to make any difference. I'd really prefer not bridging in the default netns, but also haven't tried that.

Again, not sure if I'm missing something obvious or misunderstanding something fundamental, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oops, typed it in wrong when transcribing from my terminal to the post, they're .36 not .136, sorry. That is what I ran on the server, I'll update the post.

Comment: So with the sysctl and `ip route add 192.168.136.0/24 dev veth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.25.36.1` and `ip netns exec sip ip route add 192.168.100.0/24 dev veth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.25.36.2` result is still the same. Probably isn't what I need to do anyways. I'm used to routing between interfaces just working with having ip_forward enabled, and not blocked in the firewall, without an intermediate "device" like the veth. using veth through a netns is a little out of depth at the moment. The answer is probably something obvious, but it's not coming to me so far.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have solved it. swapping the gateways so that it's the ip of the remote netns makes everything work. Not sure what I would edit the question to though? That seems more like an answer to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in the end there were 2 issues (one of which was corrected in the question, but I'm still mentionning it because it comes often with the use of `ip netns exec`).

- shell redirection issue with `ip netns exec`

  While working fine on the host (without `ip netns exec sip`), this kind of command:

  ```
  ip netns exec sip echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
  ```

  will still act upon the host, because shell redirection is performed first. It would run `echo` in the *sip* network namespace, and redirect its output on host's settings. That's the same kind of problem seen when using `sudo`, and the same methods must be used: either use `tee` , either have an equivalent command not requiring redirection at all. Here the two equivalent commands would be:

  ```
  echo 1 | ip netns exec sip tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward >/dev/null
  ip netns exec sip sysctl -q -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
  ```

  It might not have made any difference here, because when the new network namespace (`ip netns`'s *sip*) is created, it inherits the settings from where it was created. Since *host* was routing already, so would have already been *sip*. But other similar configurations intended on *sip* could have disrupted the host instead.
- wrong choice of gateway

  ```
  ip addr add 172.25.36.1/24 dev veth0
  ip route add 192.168.136.0/24 via 172.25.36.1

  ip netns exec sip ip addr add 172.25.36.2/24 dev veth0
  ip netns exec sip ip route add 192.168.100.0/24 via 172.25.36.2
  ```

  The commands won't complain. Using one own's IP as gateway is an alternate method to tell to not use any gateway (which probably even works on different OSes). The effect is the same as telling the link is direct to the related interface, so here the two route commands mostly behave the same as if they were not using `via` but using `dev veth0` like:

  ```
  ip route add 192.168.136.0/24 dev veth0
  ip netns exec sip ip route add 192.168.100.0/24 dev veth0
  ```

  which won't help anything.

  The correction is to use the peer system (host or *sip*)'s IP as the gateway instead of previous route commands. These commands which instruct each system to reach the "other side" by using the *other* system:

  ```
  ip route add 192.168.136.0/24 via 172.25.36.2
  ip netns exec sip ip route add 192.168.100.0/24 via 172.25.36.1
  ```